# Oracle SQL - Data Type

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldatatypes, sql-view

Hello I'm currently occupied to created a view in SQL. I have one issue with one data type, for my value `X_SOURCE_ADDRESS` the maximum character in this 2020 years is `18`  .

But in the DB this columns is in `VARCHAR2(255)`, in powerBi this column have a high data size.

It's possible to declare another datatype ?

Query:

[image]

Column:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortly: **CAST**.

Here's an example: table `dept` has a column named `dname` which is `varchar2(20)`:

```
SQL> desc dept
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 DEPTNO                                    NOT NULL NUMBER
 DNAME                                              VARCHAR2(20)        --> this
 LOC                                                VARCHAR2(20)
```

If I create a view, `dept` column will inherit table's datatype:

```
SQL> create view v_dept as select * from dept;

View created.

SQL> desc v_dept
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 DEPTNO                                    NOT NULL NUMBER
 DNAME                                              VARCHAR2(20)          --> this
 LOC                                                VARCHAR2(20)
```

But, if you `cast` it to something else, you'll get what you want:

```
SQL> drop view v_dept
  2  /

View dropped.

SQL> create view v_dept as
  2    select deptno,
  3           cast(dname as varchar2(50)) as dname,         --> this
  4           loc
  5    from dept;

View created.

SQL> desc v_dept
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 DEPTNO                                    NOT NULL NUMBER
 DNAME                                              VARCHAR2(50)       --> this
 LOC                                                VARCHAR2(20)

SQL>
```